# $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$ and $a>c $. Show that exists $N \in \Bbb {N}$ so that $x_n>c \forall n \ge N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$ and $a>c $ then show that exists $N \in \Bbb {N}$ such that $x_n>c , \forall n \ge N$ .
$a,c \in \Bbb{R} $ and $x_n$ is a sequence in real numbers.
I have tried to start by the definition of convergence and to replace the $a$ with $c$, but I didn't make any progress.

Comment: I am sorry but the question is very unclear, the is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that what exactly happens?

Comment: So that since that moment, the statement becomes true for all n greater or equal than N

Comment: What statement becomes true? I don't think there is a statement.

Comment: You were right, I forgot to add the statement that has to be proven. My apologies

Comment: The statement is false if I've understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $|x_n-a| <\frac {a-c} 2$ for $n \geq N$. Then $x_n >a-(\frac {a-c} 2) >c$ for $n \geq N$.